# Argument of type ''{}" is not assignable to parameter on angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to access the checkbox value on the component from html selected record. When I was implemented the checkbox toggle method on my ts file, I am getting the error like "Argument of type ''{}" is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element' at ts file",

My html file contains like the following with checkbox,

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select" >
                  <mat-header-cell style="max-width:50px;" *matHeaderCellDef>
                    <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                                  [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                                  [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                  </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell style="max-width:50px;" *matCellDef="let row">
                    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                                  (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                                  [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                  </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="UserId">
        <mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef> User ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.nUserId}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

And my .ts file contains the method to receive the toggled row like the following way,

```
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ManageuserService } from 'src/app/services/asset/manageuser.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-modifyuserpermissions',
 templateUrl: './modifyuserpermissions.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./modifyuserpermissions.component.css']
})
export class ModifyuserpermissionsComponent implements OnInit 
{
 selectedUser: string;
 selectedInstitution: string;
 filtertext:string;
 public status:boolean=false;
 public data= new Array();

 institutionalUsers: any;
 userNameDetails: any;
 userPermissionObj: any;
 permissionRequestUser: any;

 dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
 selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
displayedColumns = ['select', 'UserId','PermissionId','PermissionLevel','PermissionType'];

  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
 isAllSelected() 
  {
  const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
  const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
  return numSelected === numRows;
  }

 /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection.  */ 
 masterToggle() 
  {
   this.isAllSelected() ?
   this.selection.clear() :
   this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }


  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
          public manageuserService:ManageuserService ) { }

 ngOnInit() { 

this.manageuserService.loadUserListApiMethod()
  .subscribe((data:any)=> {this.institutionalUsers= data});
  }
 loadUserForSearchPermission(event:any,obj:any) 
  {
   if(event.isUserInput)
    {
     this.permissionRequestUser=obj.sUsername;
    }
  }

getUserPermisionsByUsernameSearch()
  {
  var param:string=this.permissionRequestUser;
    this.manageuserService.getUserPermissionApiMethod(param)
      .subscribe((data:any)=> {this.dataSource.data=[data];});
  }

}
```

red underline showing at `this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));` line.

And screenshot for the error while compiling like the following ,

[image]

Can anyone guide me to identify the root cause of this issue please?

Comment: what line is 43 in `modifyuserpermissions.component.ts`?

Comment: I think `row` is type of `object` but `this.selection.select` accepts `Element` type only.

Comment: @Jacob please share the `modifyuserpermissions.component.ts` file

Comment: @RazRonen -  this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row)); is the line no43.

Comment: @VighneshRaut - Updated in question

Comment: There are a lot of issues here. You should avoid using `var`. And type `any` in Typescript should generally not be used. Because of that, a lot of type assertions are failing. Try to fix that. It will help you in the long run. Pretty sure by fixing the types in your entire project, the error will go away.